# knoppix cd booting tar extract error

Tags: linux

I am running knoppix through a bootable cd. I tried to extract a .tar.gz with the following command.

```
tar -xvzf demo.tar.gz
```

and i am getting this error.

> gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
>   tar: Child returned status 1
>   tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

is there any other way to extract the files?

Answer (score 1):

*(A bit late for the OP, but here it goes...)*

`gzip` said it: it is not a `gzip`-compressed archive. I can think of a few alternatives:

- The filename is misleading and the file is already uncompressed - that occasionally happens when a file is downloaded using some browsers from specific servers; the browser will uncompress the file on its own without altering the its name.
- The filename is misleading and the file is compressed with some other method. Use the [`file`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command to find out what the content of the file is - it should tell you if it has been compressed with another method.
- The file is corrupt and `gzip` cannot recover. There are about a million different reasons for this to happen, from solar flares to incomplete downloads to `wget` downloading an HTML error or redirection page, rather than the file itself. You will have to procure another copy of the file...

Comment: One simple reason could be a defective burned cd, I had that several times with very cheap CD-R.